# Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\UserController::$user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

```
public function doFollow($id)
{
    $user = $this->user->getById($id);        

    if (Auth::user()->isFollowing($id)) {
        Auth::user()->unfollow($id);
    } else {
        Auth::user()->follow($id);

        $user->notify(new FollowedUser(Auth::user()));
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Do you have `$this->user` in your __construct() method?

Comment: This is where the issue is `$user = $this->user->getById($id);` ... try this instead `$user = User::find($id);`

Comment: Where is `$this->user` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can check your UserController class does have $user property if is not you must initialize in class constructor.

```
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller{

    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user){
        // İnitialize user property.
        $this->user = $user;
    }

}
```

If problem was not solved. Check your `getById` method as below.

Your `getById` method returns null object and you try access property in null object so it is undefined property.

Look `getById` method for return existing User Object. Check your query and change `find($id)` to `findOrFail($id)`. It throws Error when query not found user by given `$id`.

Or you can check and do job if user exists:

```
public function doFollow($id)
{
    $user = $this->user->getById($id);

    if($user){
        if (Auth::user()->isFollowing($id)) {
            Auth::user()->unfollow($id);
        } else {
            Auth::user()->follow($id);

            $user->notify(new FollowedUser(Auth::user()));
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```